# garbage collection of invisible variables

Tags: java, java-memory-model

I have following code:

```
void method() {
   Object o1 = new Object();
   {
      Object o2 = new Object();
      System.out.println(o2);
   }
   // any long operation
}
```

will o2 object be eligible for garbage collection during execution of `long operation`?

Comment: Your best bet is to nullify o2 when you don't need it anymore : o2 = null;

Comment: Not really worth it for one lousy Object.  Of course, if in reality you have a 100,000 byte structure of some type, then it's maybe worth it.

Comment: @JBNizet Completely useless for a non global. The object goes out of scope and isn't reachable anymore, independent of the reference being nulled or not.

Answer (score 2):

The JLS definition of reachability is:

> *"A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing
>   computation from any live thread."*

In this case, the reference ceases to be theoretically accessible to ongoing combutations *before* the `println` call returns.  (I'm assuming that `println(o2)` doesn't save its the reference somewhere.)

---

However, in practice no JVMs in existence can tell that the Object becomes unreachable during the call, and most JVMs will only notice this when ... or after ... `o2` goes out of scope.  And even then, a GC run is not guaranteed to remove the object.

---

Note: that doesn't contradict the JLS, because the "reachable object" test is really telling you when the object *won't* be garbage collected, not when it will be.  The JLS is careful to specify that an object *may* be finalized and garbage collected at some point after it becomes unreachable, but that it also *may never* be finalized and garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

yes however this will depend on whether the JVM/JIT won't optimize this to avoid superfluous stack operations

which would make it

```
Object o1 = new Object();
Object o2 = new Object();
System.out.println(o2);
// any long operation
```

many compilers will group all local variable needed and figure out the maximum needed space to keep them all (and some will be eliminated and just kept in registers) and grow the stack accordingly and only shrink it after the function can return

this would mean that o2 will remain in "accessible" memory according to GC unless it was overwritten with another variable in another scope

Comment: Even if o2 shares a stack position with a variable that's alive, I don't see any reason why the JVM should regard that memory location/register (if it knows it wasn't already overwritten by a live variable) as a root for GC? The JVM can determine at which safepoint which memory location contains a valid object and when not.. though no idea how thorough HS does this?

Comment: yeah but that requires investigating the instruction pointer and the function code itself, it's easier to just group all object references together (reusing them as needed) and when GC comes along it just needs to scan those object pointers without regard whether it's still be able to be used or not

Comment: But the JVM already knows at which safepoint it is and where the current object pointers are for this particular point. So you're doing more work by adding unnecessary objects to your root set for each safe point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that your variable `o2` and the OBJECT DESIGNATED BY `o2` are different.

The *variable* o2 is actually a pointer (though Java prefers to call them "references") and occupies 4 or 8 bytes in the automatic stack frame.  This storage is not garbage collected and only goes away when you return from the procedure (or possibly when you exit the `{}` brackets depending on compiler implementation).

The object "designated by" (pointed to by) o2 is essentially available for possible garbage collection as soon as the `new Object()` operation ends, and the existence of a pointer to it in o2 is all that prevents this.  Once the variable o2 either no longer exists in a stack frame *or has a different pointer value stored into it* then the object is eligible to be collected.

So in your particular case the answer is "maybe".  It depends on how the compiler and JIT handle the `{}`, along with a few "luck" issues as to whether, having exited the `{}` block (but not the method as a whole), the storage location for o2 is reused for something else.

Answer (score 0):

No. Even though the object referenced by o2 is not reachable, it will not be garbage-collected. It is in a state between reachable and unreachable called "invisible" because the reference variable o2 is still on the stack.

To make the object garbage-collectible, assign `o2 = null` or put that block in another function.

source: [A 2001 book on Java performance](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html)